# Tensorflow libcublas 10.0 Issue

Tags: tensorflow

Hi I've been using Adrian's guide from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/25/how-to-configure-your-nvidia-jetson-nano-for-computer-vision-and-deep-learning/

I'm attempting to run Tensorflow 1.13.1 on a Jetson Nano. When I go to initiate python and import tensorflow I get the following error:

Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tensorflow
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/home/zachwad/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
> > >           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> > >         File "/home/zachwad/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
> > >           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
> > >         File "/home/zachwad/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
> > >           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
> > >           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
> > >           return _load(spec)
> > >       ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/home/zachwad/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/zachwad/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/zachwad/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zachwad/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/zachwad/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/zachwad/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Seems related to the following [problem](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26209).

Make sure that a compatible cuda version (in this case cuda 10) is installed on your system and that the linker can find the library: libcublas.so.10.0

Tensorflow often uses older cuda versions.
Keep also in mind that tensorflow released version 2.0, which is very different from version 1.13.